# Two similar functions for writing data to binary file using BinaryWriter

Tags: c#, file, error-handling

I have two functions for writing data to binary file using `BinaryWriter`.
The first function has single data object as argument and looks as below:

```
    // write single data object to binary file
    public void AddHeaderToIndexer(string path, RollHeader header)
    {
        bool isDone = false;
        bool error = false;

        DateTime quitTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(500);

        while (!isDone && DateTime.Now < quitTime)
        {
            try
            {
                BinaryWriter writer;
                using (writer = new BinaryWriter
                    (File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
                {
                    writer.Seek((int)writer.BaseStream.Length, new SeekOrigin());
                    WriteSingleHeader(writer, header);

                    isDone = true;
                    if (error)
                        Program.logger.Write(LogLevel.Error, "Done after timeout.");
                }

                SetReadRightToFileForEveryone(path);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                if (!error)
                    Program.logger.Write(LogLevel.Error, ex.Message);
                error = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

The second is very similar, with only difference on accepting List of data objects and writing all List members to binary file. Actually, `BinaryWriter` is opened in `Create` unlike the first function, which uses `OpenOrCreate`.

```
    // write list of fdata objects to binary file
    public void WriteHeadersToIndexer(string path, List<RollHeader> headers)
    {
        bool isDone = false;
        bool error = false;

        DateTime quitTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(500);

        while (!isDone && DateTime.Now < quitTime)
        {
            try
            {
                BinaryWriter writer;
                using (writer = new BinaryWriter
                    (File.Open(path, FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    foreach (RollHeader header in headers)
                        WriteSingleHeader(writer, header);

                    isDone = true;
                    if (error)
                        Program.logger.Write(LogLevel.Error, "Done after timeout.");
                }

                SetReadRightToFileForEveryone(path);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                if (!error)
                    Program.logger.Write(LogLevel.Error, ex.Message);
                error = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not able to find some elegant solution, how to separate all duplicate code, which is around the `using BinaryWriter` block. Also, you will maybe find more elegant solution of my error handling in this case. I'll be glad for such comments, too.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to `Seek()` if you write a single item but you don't need to seek for writing multiples ? In addition can you clarify why you use different `FileMode`'s ?

Comment: @Heslacher: I am using different `FileMode`s and `Seek()` because in the first case, I write single data object to existing file, in the second case, I create new file and write all data objects from `List` to this file.

Comment: @BCdotWEB: Yes, you are right, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Both methods are `public` so I would like to suggest doing proper argument validation up front which enables you to throw the correct exceptions and return early.
- Use the `var` type if the right hand side of an assignment makes the type obvious.

  For instance

  ```
  var isDone = false;  
  var quitTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(500);
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  bool isDone = false; 
  DateTime quitTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(500);
  ```
- use braces `{}` although they might be optional. This makes your code less error prone and the intent of the code is more clear.
- Don't talk to `Program` but let `Program` pass any needed parts to your class and use it then. A child object should only talk to its parent by using events.
- you should pass the `500` ms as a optional parameter to that method. This will make your code more flexible in case you need to adjust the timeout.
- you should always try to code against interfaces rather than against concrete implementations. So either use `IList<RollHeader>` or better `IEnumerable<RollHeader>` as the passed in type of `WriteHeadersToIndexer()`. This enables you to pass for instance either an `List<RollHeader>` or `RollHeader []` to that method. In fact each type which implements `IEnumerable<T>` will be good to pass.

From the comments of the question

> I am using different FileModes and Seek() because in the first case, I write single data object to existing file, in the second case, I create new file and write all data objects from List to this file.

Based on the above I would like to suggest adding another method which is called from the former 2 methods. This new method will have one method argument being a `FileMode` value like so

```
private void WriteToIndexer(string path, IEnumerable<RollHeader> headers, FileMode mode, double timeOutMs = 500d)
{
    if (path == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException($"{path}"); }
    if (headers == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException($"{headers}"); }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) { throw new ArgumentException("Parameter may not be empty", $"{path}"); }

    if (!headers.Any()) { return; }

    bool isDone = false;
    bool error = false;

    DateTime quitTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(timeOutMs);

    while (!isDone && DateTime.Now < quitTime)
    {
        try
        {

            using (var stream = File.Open(path, mode))
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Seek((int)writer.BaseStream.Length, new SeekOrigin());
                foreach (RollHeader header in headers)
                {
                    WriteSingleHeader(writer, header);
                }

                isDone = true;

                if (error)
                {
                    Program.logger.Write(LogLevel.Error, "Done after timeout.");
                }
            }

            SetReadRightToFileForEveryone(path);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                Program.logger.Write(LogLevel.Error, ex.Message);
            }
            error = true;
        }
    }
}
```

this takes advantage of the string interpolation of C# 6.0.

No you can call this like so

```
public void AddHeaderToIndexer(string path, RollHeader header)
{
    WriteToIndexer(path, new RollHeader[] { header }, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
}
public void WriteHeadersToIndexer(string path, IEnumerable<RollHeader> headers)
{
    WriteToIndexer(path, headers, FileMode.Create);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have few questions:  **1.** Which kind of **proper argument validation** do you mean in this case?  **2.** Using of **'var'** type: I think that in case of "short-named" types, like `bool` or `DateTime` it is not necessary to loose type readability by using `var`. I'm using it rather in case of "long-named" types.  **3.** I'm using **`Program.Logger`**, which is singleton of my `Logger` class and I want to be able to use it directly, from `Program.cs` up to the last top class.

Comment: Nice work, thanks! I have only one last question about `Program.Logger` from my previous comment. You say: "Don't talk to Program", but I really don't want to pass `Logger` instance to every class which can be candidate for using it. How to solve it in different way, rather then make it static in some low level class, like in `Program.cs` in my case? (I need to log something already there).

Comment: You could either use some well known logger like log4net which has a `static LogManager.GetLogger()` method or you could extract an interface out of your implementation and either inject it into the constructor or set it as a property.